# Datastage invoked through PuTTY and Java REST web service

Tags: java, rest, datastage

I am trying to invoke from a Java REST web service an instance of IBM Datastage (IBM Information Server).

I write the following code using PuTTY and the job sequence is started correctly.

```
/app/datastage/IBM/InformationServer/Server/DSEngine/bin/dsjob -run -param ENV_ID=123 -param REPORT_ID=556516 -param REPORT_FILE=/tmp/556516.zip -param TRANSF_REQ_ID=89 -param SFTP_SERVER_HOSTNAME=XXX -param SFTP_SERVER_USER=dsadm -param SFTP_SERVER_PASSWORD=XXX PROJECT_NAME service_name
```

When I launch it from the Java code, it does not work and provides neither answer, nor error.

What do you think is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!
Long ago I posted this question and the answer was really easy: I miswrote a "-", with another sign which has a different ASCII code.

Comment: Good of you to provide the update. You can [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) after 48 hours.